# whats the difference between Trace.WriteLine and Debug.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

From what I know `Trace.WriteLine()` Writes to all Trace listeners in the `Trace.Listeners` collection, and after some research I saw that apparently `debug.Writeline()` does essentialy the same thing. whats then is the point of `debug.WriteLine()`?

Comment: `Trace.WriteLine()` outputs something for both DEBUG and RELEASE builds. `Debug.WriteLine()` only outputs something for DEBUG builds. Often you don't want to write debug output from a release build, since the end-user can see that if they use any utility that captures debug output.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the debugging works:

1. We first use `Console.WriteLine` for debugging. This will print everything on a Console. Many times, we may not have a console. Also, the purpose of `Console.WriteLine` (for console applications) is to show meaningful message to the user.
2. So, then the focus shifts to `Debug.WriteLine`. `Debug.WriteLine` prints debug information by default in Visual Studio output window (This can be configured in app.exe.config file). The tracing information is generated with Debug.WriteLine() if built with the DEBUG conditional #ifdef DEBUG. This is "on" by default in debug mode. In release mode, these calls are effectively removed generating no overhead.
3. However, now we realize we don't want to print everything in Production or release mode (like stack trace etc.) So, then we use `Trace.WriteLine` in release mode.

In debug mode we can see output from both `Debug.WriteLine()` and `Trace.WriteLine()`.
Unit Test code however supresses both `Debug.WriteLine` and `Trace.WriteLine` calls.